# Can a custom module be used to assign permissions associated with a different module?

Tags: 7, users

Drupal 7. I'm using a contrib module that has one user permission associated with it.  Enabling the module assigns that permission to only the "Administratror" role. I'd like to find a way of using a custom module to also assign the permission to a custom role I've created.

So far, I have within my custom module a function that runs when the contrib module is enabled.

```
function mycustommodule_modules_enabled($modules) {
  if (in_array('contribmodule', $modules)) {
    $roleid = array_search('custom role', user_roles());
    if (is_int($roleid)) {
      user_role_grant_permissions($roleid, array(
        'permission from contrib module' => TRUE,
      ));
    }
  }
}
```

But it results in an error like this (output from Drush):

> WD php: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
>   19 role_permission.module may not be NULL: INSERT INTO
>   {role_permission} (rid, permission,  [error] module) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
>   Array (
>       [0] => 5
>       [1] => 1
>       [2] => )  in user_role_grant_permissions() (line 3076 of /var/www/d7/modules/user/user.module). PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 19 role_permission.module may not be
>   NULL: INSERT INTO {role_permission} (rid, permission, module) VALUES
>   (?, ?, ?); Array (
>       [0] => 5
>       [1] => 1
>       [2] => )  in user_role_grant_permissions() (line 3076 of /var/www/d7/modules/user/user.module). Drush command terminated
>   abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
>   [error]

Looking at the table structure that third value [2] that's blank is supposed to be the name of the contrib module associated with the permission.

I think the problem is something along the lines of either the permission doesn't exist yet at that point in the execution, or maybe it's a security safeguard that prevents custom code from assigning permissions associated with separate modules. Either way I'd appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction with this.

Comment: Any reason not to simply click it via UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are hooks* to revoke or change permissions so there is no need to set `TRUE` or `FALSE` in your snippet.

Try this:

```
function mycustommodule_modules_enabled($modules) {
  if (in_array('contribmodule', $modules)) {
    $roleid = array_search('custom role', user_roles());
    if (is_int($roleid)) {
      user_role_grant_permissions($roleid, array(
        'permission from contrib module',
      ));
    }
  }
}
```

In this call, you are setting the array's **value** to the permission name -- Not the key.

*: [`user_role_change_permissions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_role_change_permissions/7) and [`user_role_revoke_permissions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_role_revoke_permissions/7)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! Initially I was working with user_role_change_permissions() and switched to user_role_grant_permissions() without amending what was passed to it.